# Is it possible to alias an enum-class enumerator?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, alias, language-lawyer

Given a C++11 enum class, nested inside several long- and ugly-named namespaces:

```
namespace
    long_and_ugly
{
    enum class
        colour
    {
        red,
        green,
        blue
    };
}
```

Can aliases be made of the enumeration values? With clang++ 3.5, it is possible to do what follows:

```
using long_and_ugly::colour; // take all the values into the current namespace
using long_and_ugly::colour::red; // take only 'red' into the current namespace

function_taking_colour_argument( red ); // instead of fully referring to the value
```

g++ 4.9, however, complains. I can't copy its error message because I can't access the code, but it explicitly complained about the usage of the using directive or declaration. I have also tried this:

```
using red = long_and_ugly::colour::red;
```

But it also failed. I'm sorry for not pasting the errors. Nevertheless, I believe you should be able to reproduce it.

---

#### Question(s)

- Is it possible to declare aliases to enumeration values in standard C++11, or was I using a clang extension?
- If it is, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_active.html#1742

Comment: `using red = long_and_ugly::colour::red;` That's the syntax for type aliases. I doubt it will be used for anything else soon.

Comment: @dyp Thank you, the page you linked answered my question. About your last comment, I remember g++ also complained about that form, but I will try it again anyway, as soon as I can.

Comment: Actually, are you sure clang++ puts all the enumerators "into the current namespace" when writing `using long_and_ugly::colour;`? [The clang++ at coliru disagrees](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da4b6c9545ceb212)

Comment: @dyp I'm amused. It worked, for I was able to use the aliases as template parameters.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Enumerators in *using-declarations*

The problem is that the standard says that you shall not refer to an enumerator inside an *enum class* when using specifying a *using-declaration*.

> `7.3.3p7` **The `using` declaration** `[namespace.udecl]` ([n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf))
>
> > A *using-declaration* shall not name a scoped enumerator.

```
namespace N {
  enum class E { A };
}

using N::E;    // legal
using N::E::A; // ill-formed, violation of [namespace.udecl]p7
```

<sup>**Note**: `clang` does accept both lines above; [here's a relevant bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9124).</sup>

It's perfectly fine to refer to the actual name of the *enum class* itself, but trying to refer to one of its enumerators is ill-formed.

---

### Enumerators in *alias-declarations*

The standard says that an *alias-declaration* can only be used to refer to a *type-name*, since an *enumerator* isn't a type, using one in such context is ill-formed.

```
namespace N {
  enum class E { A };
}

using x = N::E;     // legal, `N::E` is a type
using y = N::E::A;  // ill-formed, `N::E::A` isn't a type
```

---

#### Alternatives to *using-*  and *alias-declarations*

You could declare a constant having whatever-name-of-your-choice initialized with the value you'd like to "alias":

```
namespace N {
  enum class E { A };
}

constexpr N::E x = N::E::A;
```

```cpp
int main () {
  N::E value = x; // semantically equivalent to `value = N::E::A`
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Sort of:

```
namespace long_and_ugly {
    enum class colour
    {
        red,
        green,
        blue
    };
}
const colour red = long_and_ugly::colour::red;
```

Comment: Maybe also add `constexpr` and (in some contexts) `static`.